# Date Range Nested Loop Optimization

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, nested-loops, date-range

Redshift db.

Table A is a date/calendar table.

Table B is a member table.  Table B structured as a slowly changing dimension type 6. It has nearly 200 M records.

The goal is to write a performant performant query that gives the count of members for every day in the last 4 years.  My first attempted resulting in a query like so:

```
select
      date,
      location,
      sub_location,
      race,
      gender,
      dob,
      member_type,
      count(distinct member_id)

from date_table d

join member_table m
 on m.row_start <=  d.full_date
 and m.row_end >= d.full_date
 and m.is_active = 'Y'
 and m.row_end >= '2019-01-01'

where d.date_key >= 20190101
 and d.date_key <= to_char(current_date, 'yyyymmdd')

group by 
      date,
      location,
      sub_location,
      race,
      gender,
      dob,
      member_type
```

The performance on this is god awful because of the join being a nested loop.  I've been trying to think of a way to rework this to avoid that issue but have not had any success.  Curious if there is a way to do so that would increase performance significantly.

For reference here are the table designs as well as the explain plan:

```
create table date_table
(
    date_key                       integer not null encode delta
        primary key,
    full_date                      date encode delta,
)
    diststyle all
    sortkey (date_key);
```

```
create table member_tabnle
(
    member_key                 bigint not null
        primary key,
    member_id                  integer,
    location                   integer distkey,
    sub_location               integer encode zstd,
    gender                     varchar(50) encode zstd,
    race                       varchar(100) encode zstd,
    date_of_birth              date encode delta32k,
    member_type                char(10) encode zstd,
    active                     char encode zstd,
    row_start                  timestamp encode zstd,
    row_end                    timestamp encode zstd,
)
    diststyle key
    interleaved sortkey (location, member_id);
```

[execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHbNn.png)

I've rewritten the query in various ways, none of which meaningfully impacted performance.

The output should be

```
Date, member attributes, count of records
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in luck as I solved this exact issue a few years back and wrote up a description on the solution.  You can find it here - http://wad-design.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sql_limits_wp.html

The basic issue you are facing is the need to massively grow the data before you can condense it down.  These fat-in-the-middle queries can be expensive on Redshift and often spill to disk making them even more expensive.  The solution is to not create a row for each account for each date but rather to look at it as counting account starts by date and account ends by date - the active accounts is the difference between the rolling sums of these values.
I was able to take a clients query run time down from 45 minutes to 17 seconds using this approach.

If the approach isn't clear let me know in a comment and I can help apply this approach to your situation.  It can trip people up the first time.

This approach can be used to solve other problems efficiently like joining on the nearest date.

Comment: This is brilliant Bill and very helpful on getting on the right track.  This method yields extremely close results but I do need to get distinct counts because it is possible for there to be multiple record events on 1 day that just need to be counted once.  Since you cannot count distinct in windowed functions on redshift what would you recommend?

Comment: I assume that you could get other types over overlapping events so my first thought would be to prune these cases out when doing the UNION ALL phase.

Comment: That does make sense but when I get a result set like this it double counts for the 1st?

```date,id,start_dtm,end_dtm

1-24.  ,   1, 1/24/23 00:00, null

2-1.    ,   1, null                  , 2/1/23 00:00

2-1.    ,   1, 2/1/23 00:00.  , null

12-99,    1, null                 , 12/31,99 00:00```

sorry for the wonky formatting

Comment: So this looks like the data before the window functions for rolling sums, right?  And I'm guessing that you are getting an extra count on 2/1 as the id #1 stops and restarts on that day.  This is due to the built in assumption that an id is active on both the day it starts and the day it ends.  If this is not your assumption then this is easily fixed.  If you do want this behavior then I thinking there needs to be some special casing for this corner case.  Let me know if I have your situation wrong.

Comment: Correct in that my assumption is that they are active on start and end day.

Comment: So if I were to address this corner I think I'd go for a middle level of SELECT that detects this overlapping stop and start condition.  It would need to happen before the GROUP BY.  Since this means comparing rows it would require another window (or some self joining but I expect the window will be faster).  A last_value(end_date) window over partition by id, for all prev start_dates that matches the current start_date would indicate a matching start end condition which will require a -1 in the top level.

Comment: The main issue as I am currently seeing it is the last_value is associated with the end_date record, and there isn't a clear way to compare it performantly to the start_date record

Comment: Bill, I was able to solve the issue by removing the +1 on the end date in the 3rd union all statement, it now matches my truth source 100%

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach struggles to layer in the member attributes like gender, dob, etc. What is odd is that it counts some of the genders for example but not all.  I am partitioning by the attributes as such: 
(sum(count(start_date)) over (partition by gender order by mdate rows unbounded preceding ) - sum(count(end_date)) over (partition by gender order by mdate rows unbounded preceding ))  as active_accounts

Comment: Good to hear that things are matching (mostly).  If there is still an issue and help is needed I think a sqlfiddle will be needed to demonstrate the issue and speak to common data.  There's been a number of incremental changes I think I've lost an exact notion of what is going on.

Comment: Great idea Bill and thank you again for working through this with me so I can understand!  [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cb57b3/14/0) is the link to the SQLFiddle.  As you can see you can just do the mdate plus the windows to get the baseline *true* count and as you add attributes like member type, race, etc, the counts get undercounted.

Comment: @LukeSnow A few things - there was a slight mistake in the schema, and I changed the DB to postgres (closer to Redshift but a few missing functions), but the biggest issue was that to get all these other categories you need to cross join with the different category values.  Does this work?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/49a31/20

Comment: It does work, technically.  Performance has absolutely tanked however. I took the double hit to the members table out and put it in a CTE to only do the limiting once, but the query is over 30+ minutes now :(

Comment: I'm not too surprised as this puts a looped join back in thus creating a new data structure.  If this is large, especially as compared to memory in the cluster, it can be slow.  So the question is 'do you need the data broken out by all these factors?'.  Of member_type, location, sub_location, and gender which is providing the most unique values?  (Likely location and sub_location but I don't know your data.)  Removing or condensing these down could have a significant improvement in run time.

Comment: You are taking a large table of sparse data (in terms of date) and converting it to dense date data which can be done quickly.  But you also want to break this dense data out by data that has high ordinality.  This create a new, very large, data segment.  It is creating this new, large, data organization that is causing these non-linear increases in run time.  As soon as this data size exceeds memory (and is of a non-linear algorithm) execution time explode.  If the need is to have the data vs. any one of these factors you could be better off running the generating query 4 times.

Comment: @LukeSnow did those comments makes sense?  Another way to think about it is that the first SELECT in the UNION ALL list is the scaffold that has all the rows that will be in the final result.  As this scaffold grows, due to all the different ways that the data is partitioned, the size of created dataset grows.  If this to be created dataset is larger then available memory the query massively slows down.  I suspect this limit has been crossed.

Comment: So sorry for the delay - I went on PTO and lost track of this thread.  Yes! It does make sense and your help was EXTREMELY helpful in solutioning this.  Thank you!